# Get Azure standard certificate working for www

Tags: azure, ssl

I purchased a standard SSL certificate through Azure, and it forced me to remove the `www.` prefix.  I couldn't do DNS-type domain verification at the time, and imported the certificate got it verified on another means, and got the non-www url working with the new certificate.

However, when trying to bind the www version of the url, the imported certificate does not come up in the list, and the documentation indicates that this is only possible when the domain has been verified using DNS or email verification methods.

I subsequently inserted the required TXT record on the DNS for verification.  However, the certificate still does not come up in the list for binding.  Is there a way for me to get the verification done again and add www support, or is my only option to lose the money spent on a certificate and buy a new one?

Comment: Are you having difficulties on App Service or is it another service?
You may add additional SANs (Subject aletrnative Names) and reissue your ssl certificate or choose less secure route and just get wildcard certificate as in *.mydomain.com

Comment: It's on an Azure web app.  When you say "reissue", do you mean buying a new certificate, or something else like re-keying? (Wildcard is more than 4 times the cost, so don't want to do that).

Comment: App service can have multiple SSL certificates uploaded and you may select one when you bind SSL certificate to Custom domain. 
If you can't see certificate than you cant bind it.

you may try to generate own free certificate for example with [ZeroSSL](https://zerossl.com) for www subdomain and upload it to app service and check if you can select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got hold of Azure support, and they introduced me to App Service Managed Certificates, which are free for Azure Web App use.  So I created a new certificate for the www version of the domain and resolved the issue.  I wonder if this covers all my web app needs and if I'll ever need to purchase a certificate again for Azure?